# When a cell is tapped, an annotation should be added

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkannotation

I need to add an annotation to a map view when it is touched the any cell of the tableview. I have a method where I add the annotation viewForAnnotation and the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

I could not make the logical connection that is where to call the method and how?

Could you please help me?

viewForAnnotation method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView2 viewForAnnotation:(id  <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
{
    return nil;
}
else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]])
{
    static NSString * const identifier = @"MyCustomAnnotation";

    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView2 dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView)
    {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                      reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    UIImageView * ecz = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    ecz.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 49);

    ecz.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator.png"];


    UIImageView * vstd = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    vstd.frame = CGRectMake(33, 10, 24, 22);

    vstd.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator_ziyaret_gri"];


    UIImageView * nbox = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    nbox.frame = CGRectMake(48, -6, 22, 22);

    nbox.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numara_kutusu"];

    [annotationView addSubview:ecz];

    [annotationView addSubview:vstd];


    UILabel *index = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,4,15,15)];
    index.text = @"1";
    index.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [index setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18]];
    [nbox addSubview:index];
    [index setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [annotationView addSubview:nbox];

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
}

return nil;
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
EczaneCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapView: viewForAnnotation:` method is a `delegate` method of MapView, this method is called by the MapView internally when you `ADD` or, `REMOVE` any annotation from the mapview.

To add an annotation on `TableView` tap you should do the following in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[self.map addAnnotaion:<YOUR Annotation>];
```